# OpenSSL "perl Configure mingw" exits with error "perl implementation doesn't produce Unix like paths"

Tags: openssl, mingw

I'm attempting to compile OpenSSL from sources (using git master as of today) using MinGW on Windows. Running `perl Configure mingw no-asm` returns an error:

```
    This perl implementation doesn't produce Unix like paths (with forward slash
    directory separators).  Please use an implementation that matches your
    building platform.

    This Perl version: 5.24.1 for MSWin32-x86-multi-thread-64int
```

which is interesting, because it means it checks whether I'm on Unix rather than Windows. In contrast, running `perl Configure VC-WIN32 no-asm` works fine.

Is this intended that it should be checking for Unix in that case? Or maybe I'm missing something, such as a way of specifying the platform I'm on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The OpenSSL mingw build is expected to be run from an MSYS2 shell (which uses Unix style paths) and use msys2 perl. From the file "NOTES.PERL" in the OpenSSL top level directory:

```
Notes on Perl on Windows
------------------------

There are a number of build targets that can be viewed as "Windows".
Indeed, there are VC-* configs targeting VisualStudio C, as well as
MinGW and Cygwin. The key recommendation is to use "matching" Perl,
one that matches build environment. For example, if you will build
on Cygwin be sure to use the Cygwin package manager to install Perl.
For MSYS builds use the MSYS provided Perl. For VC-* builds we
recommend ActiveState Perl, available from
http://www.activestate.com/ActivePerl.
```

Really that text should be updated to explicitly say MSYS2 (in theory MSYS might work, but the version of perl provided by MSYS is too old).

Install the MSYS2 perl and that error message should go away.

Comment: This indeed has worked, I've tried perl directly (ActivePerl and Strawberry) as well as MSYS. Using MSYS2 worked. For future reference for those having similar issue, make sure you use MSYS2 perl, not the one you most likely have in your path, that is invoke the perl by specifying the full path to be sure. You can get perl through `pacman`.